# Google DFP Doubleclick for Publishers -- No 3rd Party Services Menu Link

Tags: google-dfp

From [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/188529):

> Ask your account manager to enable your DFP network for dynamic allocation. This ensures that the "3rd party services" section shows up in your DFP account so that you can complete the following instructions.

I've been asking for a month, and no answer, I keep being ignored. I do not have a 3rd party services section.

Has this been discontinued and documentation is just old?

Comment: Lots of others appear to be having this problem: [https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dfp/DnR6lYzRNZ0/j9XZo2JRCwAJ](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dfp/DnR6lYzRNZ0/j9XZo2JRCwAJ)